# Fill entire screen with a div/table with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I have a table written in HTML that I'm trying to get to display nicely on a mobile device.

The table is 100% composed of images, because it's really easy to position images if they're in a table(it's a puzzle, so positioning was a pain).

Now, before I get a few people suggesting that I should just scrap the table and use a different method of formatting these pictures -  thanks, but I'd really like to get this working before I re-write it completely. I completely appreciate the suggestion, and I definitely will get around to changing it, but for now I just need to get this specific method functional.

So basically, the table(looking like a complete image) always places itself at the upper right corner of the mobile page - here's a screenshot(cropped the URL out) https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMfY5.jpg

I'm using CSS classes to position the rows and columns, but even changing these up doesn't change anything.

Here's the code(starting at the `<meta>` tags, ending at the `</div>` tags) -

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>!!!!!</title>

    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>
  <body>
<div class="table-responsive">
            <table width="100%" id="table" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="5" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td id="one">
                        <img src="1.png" class="merge0">
                    </td>
                    <td id="two">
                        <img id="2" src="6.png" class="merge">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="three">
                        <img src="4.png" class="row1">
                    </td>
                    <td id="four">
                        <img src="2.png" class="merge1">
                    </td>
                    <td id="five">
                        <img src="7.png" class="merge2">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="six">
                        <img src="8.png" class="row2">
                    </td>
                    <td id="seven">
                        <img src="5.png" class="row3">
                    </td>
                    <td id="eight">
                        <img src="3.png" class="row4">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions, I'm really confused as to why this just won't fill my screen.

Thanks in advance,

-M

Comment: if you could recreate this problem in a bootply; i would gladly help

Comment: Never used bootply, but I'll get on it. Would it help if I gave you the URL to the site I'm trying to work on?

Also, it's very important to note that **on a desktop, the webpage displays perfectly**.

Comment: Your images arent wide enough, you'd need to scale them too, to fit all screen widths. Your layout is not bootstrap at all and you applied the table class to the wrong element. And so on and so on..

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/new# - you could supply the website as well. I am guessing it is your container.

Answer (score 8):

read bootstrap doc

## Example: Fluid container

Turn any fixed-width grid layout into a full-width layout by changing your outermost `.container` to `.container-fluid.`

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

also mobile and table doesn't go hand in hand with eachother...

Comment: This was going to be my guess; but i haven't tested.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a responsive table I found.  It should do the trick. 
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/no-more-tables-respsonsive-table